# Can I swap a shimano free hub body for a campag one and be able to attach it to the existing Deore hub?

Tags: shimano, hub, campagnolo

I want to convert my Surly Cross Check into a Campagnolo set up. The problem I am having is i have Shimano Deore Hubs on Mavic rims at present. I would rather not buy new wheels, so I am looking at the possibility of swapping the free hub body to a campag splined one free hub body.

I am finding it difficult to get answers to the question if I can swap a shimano free hub body for a campag one and be able to attach it to the existing Deore hub or if I need to replace the complete hub for a campag one?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any campy replacement freehub for a deore... esp since shimano uses different incompatible freehub bodies for its different hubs, and Deore being a mountain group, campy being mostly road, I don't see there being any market for such a conversion.

That being said, if you find a replacement campy rear hub with a similar flange size, you could just swap the hubs. YOu would need a spoke wrench and truing stand, and some general wheelbuilding knowledge.

EDIT: not sure how much of a perfectionist you are, but you could just run a campy rd and shifters on a shimano cassette. See:
http://sheldonbrown.com/drivetrain-mixing.shtml

Comment: Yeah I think you are correct, i couldn't find a campag freehub to fit a Deore hub body. I do eventually  want my bike to be perfect and run a complete campag drive train, but until I have acquired wheel building knowledge and can afford to build a new back wheel i have been looking into quick fix solutions to get the bike on the road. I have looked into running a Shimergo drive train but have opted against it for this build. I would however use this method for a commuter bike, but not necessarily for a touring bike. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest 'good' solution is probably getting a conversion cassette - campagnolo spacing but with a shimano spline so it'll fit on your existing hub.

This one from ambrosio would probably do the trick - http://www.probikekit.com.au/bicycle-cassettes-sprockets/ambrosio-cassette-shimano-fit-for-campagnolo-10-speed/10768425.html

Things will probably be harder if you want to go 11 speed though.

Comment: A conversion cassette was my next temporary quick fix option to get the pedals turning, so I have just purchased an Ambrosio 10sp Shimano spline/Campag pitch cassette. It looks pretty good and i have nearly completed building the bike so should be able to give some feedback on this set up sometime this week. thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's unlikely you're using 11-speed in this set up, but if you are, then none other than Lennard Zinn has discovered that [11-speed Shimano, SRAM and Campag are near enough in spacing to be compatible](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/09/bikes-and-tech/drivetrain-compatibility-hidden-in-plain-sight_303199).

> Had I just gotten a wheel change in a race with any of those wheels, I could have raced as hard as I wanted with nary a shift hesitation or skip and essentially perfect shifting.